# Condition to fetch only required values in a loop using PHP DOM Parser

Tags: php, dom, file-io, conditional-operator

I am trying to only return the value of a `<p>` tag if it's not 0.

So far I've tried putting up a condition to check whether the value is not zero but no success

Example of what I'm trying to attain:

Line #0 :somecontent NOTZERO

Line #3 :somecontent NOTZERO

```
 <?php


    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
    $url="http://somedomain/something/";
    $lines = file('text.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    if ($line_num % 2 == 1) {
        continue; // Skip odd lines
    }



    echo  "<br />\n"."Line #<b>{$line_num}</b>  :" .(htmlspecialchars($line."\t"));
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url.$line);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node) {

    // do stuff with $node

    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";  




    }
    }   



   ?>
```

Also, can you suggest me something to speed the execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I imagined. Hope someone finds this useful someday

```
<?php
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300000);
    $url="http://somedomain/something/";
    $lines = file('text.txt',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line){
    if ($line_num % 2 == 1) {
        continue; // Skip odd lines
    }




    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTMLFile($url.$line);
    foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('p') as $node) {
    // do stuff with $node

    if($node->nodeValue!="0"){

    echo  "<br />\n"."Line #<b>{$line_num}</b>  :" .(htmlspecialchars($line."\t\t"));

    echo $node->nodeValue, "\n";  




    }
    }
}   




   ?>
```